# CSS replace value by add pixel to old

Tags: css

i have:

```
#mydiv { height: 100px; }
```

i want to change height by replace, but i have to add e.g. 50 px

```
#mydiv { height: OLD_VALUE + 50px; }
```

Is it possible without js?

Comment: Do you need to do this dynamically on a web page? Or do you want to be able to do this in your css file?

Comment: You can `Sass` or `Less` for that

Comment: i want do this in css files. someone write e.g. #mydiv { height: 100px; } but then value has to be increased about 50px
I can't use Sass and Less. Sass and less use js.

Comment: @user3808177 Sass does not -- http://sass-lang.com/guide

Answer (score 0):

You can't -- CSS doesn't have any notion of this.  While you may be able to do something like using CSS3 variables and `calc`, it would require the original CSS file to use the variables.

First file:

```
:root {
    var-height: 100px;
}

#myDiv {
    height: var(height);
}
```

Your file:

```
#myDiv {
    height: calc(var(height) + 50px);
}
```

The best/typical approach to this would be to do it via Javascript, or otherwise something like SASS.

Comment: it isn't a constant. look: one person write in first file e.g. #mydiv { height: 100px; }  and then second file has to increase this value( about 50px)

Comment: @user3808177 Is 50px not a constant?

Comment: @user3808177 Also, if you know the previous value and you know the value you need to add, couldn't you just overwrite the rule?

Comment: sorry,misunderstanding. yes 50px is constant, i don't know previous value

Comment: I need to have old value from myDiv not his parent

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. You have to use JS for this.
But you can use `margin`s or `padding`s to increace distance in certain direction
P.S. In JS you can use `+=50px` for that

Comment: @igor-shults , are you sure? I think, that "height: 150%" will make element take 150% of its container's height

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS3 `calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) though you'll need to be [wary of support](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Comment: i know, but i don't know how can i get old value to this operation.